# Разделить большой файл txt на python

Tags: python, файлы

Значит есть задача, разделить один файл на несколько, что казалось бы легко, накидал я значит г**но код, все работает, но возникла проблема, при работе с файлами больше 10гб программа отказывается работать, запускается, повисает и закрывается. Может кто знает как разделить такие файлы? Все способы, что есть в интернете уже перепробовал.

```
import os
import threading
import time
import math

files = os.listdir()

s = 0
for x in files:
    if x == 'split':
        s = s + 1

if s != 1:
    os.mkdir('split')

def splitter(i, file_count, line_in_file_count, line_count):
    count = 0
    res = []
    res.append('')
    inp = open(i, 'r', encoding='ANSI')
    file_meter = 1
    line_meter = 1
    for file_meter in range(file_count):
        out_name = 'split/' + str(file_meter) + '.txt'
        out = open(out_name, 'w', encoding='ANSI').close()
        out = open(out_name, 'w', encoding='ANSI')
        for line_meter in range(line_in_file_count):
            if count <= line_count:
                for line in inp:
                    res[0] = line
                    count = count + 1
                    break
                if count <= line_count:
                    out.write(str(res[0]))
        out.close()



    inp.close()


for i in files:
    line_in_file_count = 0
    txt = i.endswith('.txt')
    if txt == True:

        line_count = sum(1 for line in open(i, 'r'))
        oper_id = int(input('В файле {} строк\nДля разбития на количество файлов введите 0, для разбития по количеству строк в файле введите 1: '.format(line_count)))
        start = time.time()
        if oper_id == 0:
            file_count = int(input('Введите количество файлов: '))
            line_in_file_count = math.ceil(line_count/int(file_count))
            print(line_in_file_count)
            splitter(i, file_count, line_in_file_count, line_count) 

        if oper_id == 1:
            line_in_file_count = input('Введите количество строк в файле: ')
            file_count = line_in_file_count =math.ceil(line_count/int(line_in_file_count))  
            print(file_count)       
            splitter(i, file_count, line_in_file_count, line_count)             


end = time.time()
print('DONE!\nWorking time:{}s\nThe program will automatically close after 5 seconds!'.format(round(end - start)))
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Может быть вам не хватает опертиавной памяти?)

Comment: Был вариант такой, запускали на компьютере с 32гб оперативной памяти, результат 0

Comment: было бы неплохо показать г**но код... Ведь программисты - не телепаты.

Comment: И уточните, что значит "программа отказывается работать". Как именно этот отказ проявляется?

Comment: Не работает в плане повисает и закрывается, а выхлопа 0

Comment: @DmitriyCooper 32гб ОЗУ, файл в 10гб, думаете не хватает?

Comment: @ArtsemPratayeu, прям совсем 0? Ни трейсбэка, ни кода завершения процесса, просто вылет и всё? Или программа нормально завершается?

Comment: @Bogdan совсем прям совсем

Comment: Наверняка все загибается еще на этапе `line_count = sum(1 for line in open(i, 'r'))`. Обработать 10 гб текста просто чтобы посчтать количество строк... это не быстро, особенно на python.

Comment: @extrn какие есть варианты для подсчета чтобы не загибала? мне важен этот параметр, так как программа должна делить как на количество файлов указанное пользователем, так и на количество строк в одном файле указанное пользователем

Comment: Ну в теории ничего делать не нужно, просто ждать. Ничего не происходит __пока__, просто потому, что программа молча считает количество строк. как закончит - начнет делить файл на куски. Ну либо думать над оптимизацией алгоритма, чтобы вывести большую часть операций из медленного пользовательского кода в быстрый код интерпретатора. Потестируйте для начала на файле меньшего (но не совсем маленького размера) - хотя бы на 500 мб.

Comment: @extrn программа без проблем работает с файлами в несколько гигабайт, но как только объем файла добирается до 10гб, то все, запускается и сразу повисает, через пару секунд вылетает

Comment: Можно попробовать читать файл кусками и записывать эти куски в другой файл, по достижении какого-то большого размера получаемого файла - писать в следующий потом уже полученные файлы поменять так, чтоб они удовлетворяли требованиям. То есть сначала разбить большой файл так, как удобно Вам, а потом уже полученные разбить так, как хочет пользователь

Comment: какие есть варианты читать кусками, можете посоветовать?

Comment: Метод `read` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: @ArtsemPratayeu, если речь идёт о 10+G файлах, а не о лабораторной работе по Python, то лучше воспользоваться инструментом, специально созданным и оптимизированным для этого - [split](https://www.linuxtechi.com/split-command-examples-for-linux-unix/). [Здесь](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) можно найти многие UNIX утилиты портированные на Windows

Comment: @MaxU возможно, но программа split.exe не доступна для скачивания